# Will a cookie with Max-Age=1 be handled reliably?

Tags: cookies, browser, webserver, fetch-api, rfc

I'm trying to create a "one time" cookie, that should be removed as soon as the response is properly handled.

The thought occurred to use `Max-Age` to basically skip part of the invalidating logic, by setting it to `1`, and let the user agent expire it automatically. It sounds almost too easy, so can this be relied upon, for example if more than a second passed between request and response?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused. Or may be I misunderstand your opinion. You want to disable the cookie as soon as the connection is settled, does this operation due to the consideration of security? So why trying to use cookie? Cookie is used to tell if two requests come from the same browser like keeping a user logged in. If you insist on using cookies, the situation you mentioned in your question may not occur. Or you can set the Max-Age as -1, so as soon as the page is closed, the cookies will turn to expired itself.

Hope my answer can help you, if I misunderstand your oponion, please let me know and let's see what else can I do for you.
Great day.